# With or by + gerund

Tags: prepositions

> 1. By stealing that money he can pay all his debts

Or

> 2. With stealing that money he can pay all his debts?

I think ***with*** is correct here.

Cz that'd mean

With the help of stealing that money, he can pay all his debts

Comment: Your first example is correct. The preposition phrase _by stealing that money_ acts as a 'means adjunct'. It expresses the means by which he can pay all his debts.

Comment: You may exlude the preposition and say, "**Stealing that money he can pay all his debts**"

Answer (score 1):

In this case it would be #1 because this use of by is on, as a means of conveyance:

`They arrived by ship.`

Comment: What if i use with? That wont sound wrong though

Comment: @user236989 - *With* sounds wrong.  *By* means "by means of" or "through using".  *With* doesn't mean that.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is the first one. The preposition "by" indicates that the purpose of stealing that money is to pay all his debts.

See http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/by

```
c - used to indicate an action that is done for a particular purpose
    * You can reset the machine by pressing this button. [=you can press this button to reset the machine]
    * He began his speech by thanking the President and ended it by telling a joke.
```

The preposition "with" indicates what he can use to pay all his debts. There is no sense of him performing an action to pay them.

```
With that money he can pay all his debts.
```

or

```
With the stolen money he can pay all his debts. [The money was already stolen.]
```